# Как h1 и p расположить в одну строку и по центру страницы?

Tags: html, css

Так вывожу:

`echo "<div class='cent'> <h1> DATABASEs, my man </h1><p class='success'> success connect</p> </div>";`

В файле стилей `h1, .success {display: inline-block;}` - объеденились в строку в левом углу.

Стиль `.cent {  position:relative;  margin: 10px auto;}` - добавляются только вертикальные отступы.
Position`ы менял на relative - тоже без толку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.cent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: Благодарю. Не подскажите, почему margin не срабатывал?

Answer (score 1):

Поместите эти тэги в элемент-контейнер, к примеру, `div` и только потом применяйте к нему `margin: 0 auto;`. Так он со своим содержимым поместится по центру, если его ширина меньше ширины документа.
Они самостоятельно не могут расположиться по центру, потому что, как вы сами писали, они `inline`.

Comment: спасибо за правку

Comment: рад помочь ^__^